# Fastapi with tortoise-orm models early init models still not found

Tags: model, fastapi, init, tortoise-orm

I am new to API dev, and I am trying to use `tortoise-orm` with `fastapi` but with a bit different folder structure  (for user model for example src-> models->user.py):
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sobpm.png)

The main.py is located in the src folder and
the issue occurs when I try to utilise the Tortoise models early init before `register_tortoise` like in ([Model Relationships not showing in Tortoise-ORM + FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879512/model-relationships-not-showing-in-tortoise-orm-fastapi/65881146#65881146)). The result is models are still not found.

The main issue started when `related_fields` wasn't included in results and I am struggling with the solution itself in the database config file.

```cpp
import importlib
from fastapi import FastAPI
from tortoise import Tortoise
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise

mdls=importlib.import_module("models")

#for mysql database
def get_mysql_db_uri(*, user, host, db_name):
    return f'mysql://{user}@{host}:3306/{db_name}'
#for sqlite database
def get_sqlite_db_uri( db_name_with_extension):
    return f'sqlite://{db_name_with_extension}'

def setup_database(app: FastAPI):
    Tortoise.init_models(["models"], 'models')
    register_tortoise(
        app,
        db_url="sqlite://testtort.db",
        modules={
            'models': [
                "models" 
            ],
            "default_connection": "default",
        },
        generate_schemas=True,
        add_exception_handlers=True,
        
    )
    Tortoise.init_models(["models"], 'models')# i've tryed Tortoise.init_models(["models.user","models.task","models.client"], 'models')
```

I also tried `modules={'models': ["models.user","models.task","models.client"],`
if I use 'models':["models"] in both. The app starts but no database is created and no related fields for foreign key are showing.

Is the issue in the structure / models paths? I also found that using  `src.models.user` didn't work as well.

I then tried applying the solution of ([Fastapi/Tortoise early model init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257307/fastapi-tortoise-early-model-init))
([Model Relationships not showing in Tortoise-ORM + FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879512/model-relationships-not-showing-in-tortoise-orm-fastapi/65881146#65881146))

**Update:**
I was able to run the app by removing the default connection from the database configuration file, but no related fields are showing until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the solution , a couple of things to :
1- remove Default Connexion from database setup
2- put `Tortoise.init_models(["models.user","models.task","models.client"], 'models')`
on the top of each pydantic schema file (before creating dypandic models)