# How to make pydantic await on a async property (tortoise-orm's reverse ForeignKey)?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

(MRE in the bottom of the question)

In tortoise-orm, we have to await on reverse ForeignKey field as such:

```py
comments = await Post.get(id=id).comments
```

But in fastapi, when returning a Post instance, pydantic is complaining:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for PPost
response -> comments
  value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
```

It makes sense as `comments` property returns coroutine. And I had to use this little hack to get aronud:

```py
post = Post.get(id=id)
return {**post.__dict__, 'comments': await post.comments}
```

However, the **real issue** is when I have multiple relations: return a user with his posts with its comments. In that case I had to transform into dict my entiry model in a very ugly way (which doesn't sound good).

Here is the code to reproduce (tried to keep it as simple as possible):

**models.py**

```py
from tortoise.fields import *
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import Tortoise, run_async

async def init_tortoise():
    await Tortoise.init(
        db_url='sqlite://db.sqlite3',
        modules={'models': ['models']},
    )
    await Tortoise.generate_schemas()

class User(Model):
    name = CharField(80)

class Post(Model):
    title = CharField(80)
    content = TextField()
    owner = ForeignKeyField('models.User', related_name='posts')

class PostComment(Model):
    text = CharField(80)
    post = ForeignKeyField('models.Post', related_name='comments')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_async(init_tortoise())

__all__ = [
    'User',
    'Post',
    'PostComment',
    'init_tortoise',
]
```

**main.py**

```py
import asyncio
from typing import List

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel

from models import *


app = FastAPI()

asyncio.create_task(init_tortoise())

# pydantic models are prefixed with P
class PPostComment(BaseModel):
    text: str

class PPost(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str
    comments: List[PPostComment]
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class PUser(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    posts: List[PPost]
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

@app.get('/posts/{id}', response_model=PPost)
async def index(id: int):
    post = await Post.get_or_none(id=id)
    return {**post.__dict__, 'comments': await post.comments}

@app.get('/users/{id}', response_model=PUser)
async def index(id: int):
    user = await User.get_or_none(id=id)
    return {**user.__dict__, 'posts': await user.posts}
```

`/users/1` errors out with:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for PUser
response -> posts -> 0 -> comments
  value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
```

Also you may wish to put this into **init.py** and run:

```py
import asyncio
from models import *

async def main():
    await init_tortoise()
    u = await User.create(name='drdilyor')
    p = await Post.create(title='foo', content='lorem ipsum', owner=u)
    c = await PostComment.create(text='spam egg', post=p)

asyncio.run(main())
```

What I want is to make pydantic automatically await on those async fields (so I can just return Post instance). How is that possible with pydantic?

---

Changing `/posts/{id}` to return the **post** and its **owner** without comments is actually working when using this way (thanks to @papple23j):

```py
    return await Post.get_or_none(id=id).prefetch_related('owner')
```

But not for reversed foreign keys. Also `select_related('comments')` didn't help, it is raising `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I was sooo dumb.

One solution I though about is to use `tortoise.contrib.pydantic` package:

```
PPost = pydantic_model_creator(Post)
# used as
return await PPost.from_tortoise_orm(await Post.get_or_none(id=1))
```

But as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65533087/13449712), it is needed to initialize Tortoise before declaring models, otherwise Relation's wont be included. So I was tempted to replace this line:

```
asyncio.create_task(init_tortoise())
```

...with:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(init_tortoise())
```

But it errored out `event loop is already running` and removing uvloop and [installing nest_asyncio helped with that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847214/13449712)

---

### The solution I used

As per [documentation](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#fetching-the-foreign-object):

> Fetching foreign keys can be done with both async and sync interfaces.
>
> Async fetch:
>
> ```
> events = await tournament.events.all()
> ```
>
> Sync usage requires that you call fetch_related before the time, and then you can use common functions.
>
> ```
> await tournament.fetch_related('events')
> ```

After using `.fetch_related)` (or `prefetch_related` on a queryset), reverse foreign key would become an iterable, which can be used just as list. But pydantic would still be complaining that is not a valid list, so validators need be used:

```
class PPost(BaseModel):
    comments: List[PPostComment]

    @validator('comments', pre=True)
    def _iter_to_list(cls, v):
        return list(v)
```

(Note that validator can't be async, as far as I know)

And since I have set `orm_mode`, I have to be using `.from_orm` method :

```
return PPost.from_orm(await Post.get_or_none(id=42))
```

> Remember, a few hours of trial and error can save you several minutes of looking at the README.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, I found it very helpful. I have been trying to solve this for a while

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `prefetch_related()`

For example:

```py
@app.get('/posts/{id}', response_model=PPost)
async def index(id: int):
    post = await Post.get_or_none(id=id).prefetch_related('comments')
    return {**post.__dict__}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but unfortunately that didn't work, it raises `response -> comments
  field required (type=value_error.missing)` and when i change it to `return {**post.__dict__, 'comments': post._comments}` or `return post` (whith orm mode enabled), it is still complaining that comments is not of list type

Answer (score 1):

(The following text is translated using DeepL)

There is a way to do this, but it is a bit tricky

First split the pydantic models snippet into **schemas.py**

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List


# pydantic models are prefixed with P
class PPostComment(BaseModel):
    text: str
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True # add this line

class PPost(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    content: str
    comments: List[PPostComment]
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class PUser(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    posts: List[PPost]
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Next, rewrite **models.py**

```py
from tortoise.fields import *
from tortoise.models import Model
from tortoise import Tortoise, run_async

from schemas import *

async def init_tortoise():
    await Tortoise.init(
        db_url='sqlite://db.sqlite3',
        modules={'models': ['models']},
    )
    await Tortoise.generate_schemas()

class User(Model):
    name = CharField(80)
    _posts = ReverseRelation["Post"] #1

    @property
    def posts(self): #3
        return [PPost.from_orm(post) for post in self._posts]

class Post(Model):
    title = CharField(80)
    content = TextField()
    owner = ForeignKeyField('models.User', related_name='_posts') #2
    _comments = ReverseRelation["PostComment"] #1
    
    @property
    def comments(self): #3
        return [PPostComment.from_orm(comment) for comment in self._comments]

class PostComment(Model):
    text = CharField(80)
    post = ForeignKeyField('models.Post', related_name='_comments') #2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_async(init_tortoise())

__all__ = [
    'User',
    'Post',
    'PostComment',
    'init_tortoise',
]
```

where

#1: Use `ReverseRelation` to declare the reverse field, here use the prefix of the bottom line to differentiate

#2: Modify the `related_name`

#3: Write a property function and return the corresponding pydantic model list, here you don't need to use `await` because the default is to access it with `prefetch_related()`

Finally, the **main.py**

```py
import asyncio
from typing import List

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

from models import *
from schemas import *
from tortoise.query_utils import Prefetch

app = FastAPI()

asyncio.create_task(init_tortoise())

@app.get('/posts/{id}', response_model=PPost)
async def index(id: int):
    post = await Post.get_or_none(id=id).prefetch_related('_comments') #1
    return PPost.from_orm(post) #2

@app.get('/users/{id}', response_model=PUser)
async def index(id: int):
    user = await User.get_or_none(id=id).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('_posts',queryset=Post.all().prefetch_related('_comments')) #3
    )
    return PUser.from_orm(user) #2
```

where

#1: Use `prefetch_related()` to prefetch related data

#2: For a tortoise model with `orm_mode = True`, you can use `from_orm` to convert it to a pydantic model.

#3: For multi-layer correlation data structure, you need to write another layer of `prefetch_related()`

Comment: very sorry for such a delayed response, thanks, yeah it is working and i like the solution, but ideally i wouldn't use schemas from models,